# Missing Bluetooth Drivers After Windows 10 Upgrade

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, windows-10-upgrade

People keep saying to disable/delete/turn on a bluetooth driver that is no where to be found?

Here is the kicker! I downloaded a bluetooth installer here is what it said:

> No unconfigured bluetooth devices found. You should either uninstall existing bluetooth adapters or reboot your computer

I was going to use a blue tooth keyboard but now I can see that is probably not going to work.

Comment: Cool story, I always wanted to be a *blue tooth keyboard* too!

Comment: Try looking for appropriate software on the manufacturer's website for your PC.

Comment: Common to lose devices like Bluetooth when "upgrading to W-10".  Unfortunately, it's difficult to tell in advance what drivers will no longer work when upgrading.  Just another "brick in the wall" I guess.  At least you didn't lose your WiFi, and many users have reported.

Comment: Look in device manager, see if there is a bluetooth device, if there is right click on it and choose uninstall, reboot the pc, see if this helps.

Comment: also...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EllBUU7DpVA

Comment: Or...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kO0x2dvtsDA&src_vid=EllBUU7DpVA&annotation_id=annotation_463941799&feature=iv

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the make and model of your PC, your bluetooth adapter and keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

2 things to try

Open Device Manager, expand the Bluetooth Service, right click on the first  entry and select properties, go to the drivers Tab and hit the Update Driver button, then select "Search Automatically for updated driver software", see if it finds a more suitable driver.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Also check Windows Services to see that the Bluetooth Service is configured properly, startup should be set to "Automatic"

[image]
[image]